# Argument 2 passed to sqlsrv_connect() must be of the type array, string given

Tags: php, sql-server

Procurei em muitos lugares e fiquei abismado por não encontrar quase nada de PHP OO usando SQL Server. Resumindo não consigo entender o que está errado aqui, penso encarecidamente ajuda, desde já agradeço.

```
<?php

class Conexao{
    private $Localhost  = 'NOTEBOOK101010\SQLEXPRESS';
    private $User  = 'sa';
    private $Pass  = '';
    private $Database  = 'ALISON';
    private $Con = null;
    private $Coninfo = null;

    function __construct() {
        $this->Coninfo;
    }

    public function Conectar(){
        $this->Localhost;
        $this->User;
        $this->Pass;
        $this->Database;

        $this->Con = array("Database" => $this->Localhost, "UID" => $this->User, "PWD" => $this->Pass);
        $this->Coninfo = sqlsrv_connect($this->Con, $this->Database);

        if($this->Coninfo){
            echo "Conectou";
            return true;
        }else{
            die(print_r(sqlsrv_error(), true));
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Essa é minha classe Conexão a seguir minha classe Administrador

```
<?php
include_once 'Conexao.class.php';
class Administrador {
    private $Nome;
    private $Endereco;
    private $Telefone;
    private $Con;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->Con = new Conexao();
    }

    public function inserir($Nome, $Endereco, $Telefone){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO CADPES (NOME, ENDERECO, NUMERO)VALUES($this->Nome, $this->Endereco, $this->Telefone)";
        $query = sqlsrv_query($this->Con->Conectar(), $sql);
    }

}
```

Gostaria de saber onde estou errando !

Comment: Coloca a mensagem completa do erro na pergunta.

Comment: falta um `return` após essa linha `$this->Coninfo = sqlsrv_connect($this->Con, $this->Database);` ou seja, return `$this->Coninfo;` se estiver tudo certo falta isso. Também tem problemas de design mais isso é um outra história

Comment: Não resolveu =( esse é o erro    Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to sqlsrv_connect() must be of the type array, string given, called in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A passagem dos argumentos está trocada em [sqlsrv_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php) a assinatura da função é

> sqlsrv_connect ( string $serverName [, array $connectionInfo ] )

Mude:

```
$this->Coninfo = sqlsrv_connect($this->Con, $this->Database);
```

Para:

```
$this->Coninfo = sqlsrv_connect($this->Database, $this->Con);
```

Comment: sim, realmente ajudou bastante essa troca vlw, porém agora estou com erro na query eu até alterei para sqlsrv_query($this->Con->Conectar(), $sql) mas me retorna isso sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Comment: @AlisonPaulo `sqlsrv_query()` é necessario informar 3 argumentos, nessa ordem, conexão, string sql e valores. Altere seu código para:  `$sql = "INSERT INTO CADPES (NOME, ENDERECO, NUMERO)VALUES(?,?,?)";
$params = array($this->Nome, $this->Endereco, $this->Telefone);
$query = sqlsrv_query($this->Con->Conectar(), $sql, $params);`

Comment: verdade, eu vi no php.net a sintaxe, fiz isso que vc falou mas ainda está retornando o mesmo erro já não sei o que faço =( mas mesmo assim vlw

Comment: @AlisonPaulo veja se aparece algum erro assim, `sqlsrv_query($this->Con->Conectar(), $sql, $params) or die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors()))`

Comment: já tinha feito isso trás a mesma coisa An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query